# Bound for $\text{Var}[\min\{X,Y\}]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, random-variables

In https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15970/what-is-the-variance-of-the-maximum-of-a-sample, it is proved that $\text{Var}[\max\{X,Y\}]\leq\text{Var}[X]+\text{Var}[Y]$, where $X$ and $Y$ are any two random variables and $\text{Var}$ denotes the variance operator. My question is whether a similar bound holds for $\min\{X,Y\}$, such as $\text{Var}[\min\{X,Y\}]\leq \text{Var}[X]+\text{Var}[Y]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Just use the facts that $\min \{-X,-Y\}=-\max \{X,Y\}$ and  variance of $Z$ is same as variance of $-Z$ for any random variable $Z$.